# Configure MySQL Replication with k8s StatefulSet

Tags: mysql, azure, docker, kubernetes

## Spec

1. k8s cluster

   1. [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/ko-kr/services/kubernetes-service/)
   2. version: 1.18.14
2. StorageClass

   1. azure files dynamic

## Info

I made an effort to implement MySQL Replication in k8s by referring to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/).

However, when I try to implement it in the same way as the official document, I get an error.

## Error

A `Warning BackOff 3m32s (x26 over 8m27s) kubelet Back-off restarting failed container` error occurred at index 0 `mysql-0 pod` of StatefulSet.

After confirming the error that occurred inside the container, the internal log is displayed as a result, as shown below.

```
2021-04-06 13:36:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
2021-04-06 13:36:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-04-06 13:36:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
2021-04-06 13:36:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-04-06T13:36:35.449017Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-04-06T13:36:35.465160Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2021-04-06T13:36:35.465207Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Have you ever encountered an error during the training? Or do you know why it happens?

There seems to be a case of success through the official documentation, but I haven't been able to find out what's wrong with it.

To solve the error that occurs inside the mysql container, I version up the mysql image version and added `args: ["--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"]` and tried a lot of similar actions. I couldn't find it.

As it is an excerpt from the official document, I don't think it is a problem with the code itself as above.
The one I doubt is the StorageClass.

The code used in the lab is in [github](https://github.com/ruddms936/helloworld-kubernetes/tree/main/application/mysql-replicated-stateful).

> There is nothing different from the official documentation other than a small name change.

Any help would be appreciated. I definitely want to implement it.

Comment: In my view, this is pretty old way to get clustered mysql. Sorry for not having a solution, but alternative. So it doesn't use operator's capabilities - manage replicas pods automatically to solve various clustering problems. If you ask which solutions have operator, these are here: https://www.percona.com/doc/kubernetes-operator-for-pxc/index.html https://github.com/presslabs/mysql-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my experience, the issue is caused by the StorageClass, but it's not itself. It's a known problem about the Azure File Share. When the File Share mounts to the container, it has the `root` owner, not the needed user `mysql` and this causes the problem. The solution is to use the managed disk StorageClass. And in AKS, the default StorageClass is for the managed disk:

[image]

So just use the default StorageClass.

Answer (score 0):

The error you encounter:

```
[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
```

means that your data directory is not empty. In order to solve it you can:

- remove the contents of the data directory
- choose another data directory or rename it
- make sure the dir before `/var/lib/mysql` is also empty, eg: `/empty-folder:/var/lib/mysql`

Based on the linked docs you provided the actual data directory refers to `/var/lib/mysql` so you should check there.

As for the Warnning:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

I found that:

> `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` is itself deprecated because its only
> purpose is to permit control over deprecated `TIMESTAMP` behaviors that
> are to be removed in a future release of MySQL. When removal of those
> behaviors occurs, `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` no longer has any
> purpose, and you can expect it to be removed as well.

More details are documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp).